# Batch Renaming Folders

Tags: finder, folders, mojave, macos

Is there a way to batch replace current folder names with increasing numbers? The "Rename Finder Items" built-in feature only lets you replace in the 'Find and replace text' kind of way. Not all my current folder names have common characters. 
I'm using Mojave, btw.

[image]

Comment: You could try and do it with a bash script.  As noted here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216659/how-to-rename-all-files-with-special-characters-and-spaces-in-a-directory I like @eapo's solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an AppleScript solution that is quite efficient.  You can save this code in script editor.app as an application.

```
set newName to 0
set theFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose Folder" with invisibles)

tell application "Finder"
    set theFolders to folders of theFolder 
    set sortedFolders to sort theFolders by name
    repeat with i from 1 to count of sortedFolders
        set newName to newName + 1
        set thisItem to item i of sortedFolders
        set name of thisItem to newName
    end repeat
end tell
```

[image]

If you would prefer the single digit folder names to appear as double digit (01,02,03 etc.), use this following version of the script instead

```
set newName to 0
set theFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose Folder" with invisibles)

tell application "Finder"
    set theFolders to folders of theFolder
    set sortedFolders to sort theFolders by name
    repeat with i from 1 to count of sortedFolders
        set newName to newName + 1
        set thisItem to item i of sortedFolders
        if newName is less than 10 then
            set name of thisItem to 0 & newName as string
        else
            set name of thisItem to newName
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

This following AppleScript code will rename the files in the chosen folder, rather than renaming folders.

```
set newName to 0
set theFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose Folder" with invisibles)

tell application "Finder"
    set theFiles to files of theFolder
    set sortedFiles to sort theFiles by name
    repeat with i from 1 to count of sortedFiles
        set newName to newName + 1
        set thisItem to item i of sortedFiles
        set nameExtension to name extension of thisItem
        if newName is less than 10 then
            set name of thisItem to 0 & newName & "." & nameExtension as string
        else
            set name of thisItem to newName & "." & nameExtension as string
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I edit this to work for images? Or, individual files instead of folders?

Comment: @usuallystuck I added a third version of the code to rename files instead of folders

Answer (score 6):

Select all the folders you want to rename, right click them and select "Rename [number] Items..."

When you use the "Rename Finder Items" feature, you have to change it from "Replace Text" to "**Format**" in the drop down menu:

[image]

Now you can rename it however you want:

[image]